# Html.DropDownListFor() set default selected value MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to set the default selected value in DropDownListFor when the element is created

Data model:

```
public class CascadingDropDownModel
{
    public int? PreviousFirstListId { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedFirstListId { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedSecondListId { get; set; }

    public string FirstTextHint { get; set; }
    public string SecondTextHint { get; set; }

    public IList<DropDownElement> FirstDropDownData { get; set; }
    public IList<DropDownElement> SecondDropDownData { get; set; }

    public CascadingDropDownModel()
    {
        FirstDropDownData = new List<DropDownElement>();
        SecondDropDownData = new List<DropDownElement>();
    }
}
```

Partial view (doesn't work):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
                m => m.SelectedFirstListId,
                new SelectList(Model.FirstDropDownData, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedFirstListId),
                Model.FirstTextHint)
```

Partial view (work):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
                m => m.SelectedFirstListId,
                new SelectList(Model.FirstDropDownData, "Id", "Name", 5),
                Model.FirstTextHint)
```

Please, tell me what the problem is?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get error(( just an element does not choose received value

Comment: when page first load if `SelectedFirstListId` is null, of course won't  select any value...

Comment: I using this DropDownList in Ajax.BeginForm and SelectedFirstListId isn't null

Comment: @PavelIvanov, please share more of your code. You should include all of your Ajax Form and explain more of your issue. You did not share anywhere near enough for anyone to understand or help.